# Юнит тестирование асинхронных сетевых методов

Tags: java, android, vkontakte-api, юнит-тесты, тестирование

Есть допустим такой метод, он делает запрос через `VKApi` и получает `id` аватарки пользователя

```
private fun getPhotoIdByUser(userId: String) {
    val fields = "crop_photo"
    val request = VKApi.users().get(VKParameters.from(VKApiConst.USER_ID, userId,
            VKApiConst.COUNT, 1, VKApiConst.FIELDS, fields))

    request.executeWithListener(object : VKRequest.VKRequestListener() {
        override fun onComplete(response: VKResponse?) {

            val id = response?.json?.getJSONArray("response")
                    ?.getJSONObject(0)?.getJSONObject("crop_photo")
                    ?.getJSONObject("photo")?.getString("id")

        }

        override fun onError(error: VKError?) {
            Log.e("tag", "error")
        }
    })
}
```

Я знаю какой `id` должен вернуться. Но как сравнить фактический результат с ожидаемым результатом, если метод ничего не возвращает? 
Возможно ли что-то сделать с методом, чтобы появилась возможность тестирования?

Comment: совсем не понятна идея onComplete(), получает id и никуда его не сохраняет, в чем смысл ?

Comment: @keekkenen смысл в передачи id в другой метод или возвращение id из метода

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, вам надо сделать так, чтобы метод что-то возвращал.

1. Если у VkSdk есть возможность делать синхронные запросы - то используйте их, вручную запуская методы не на UI потоке.
2. Если нет возможности синхронного вызова - придётся делать это вручную. Например можно обернуть все запросы в `Observable` из либы `rxJava`. Далее у вас будет возможность тестировать их встроенными в либу способами. Типа `myMethodWhichReturnsObservableWhichContainsVkSdkAsyncRequest().test().assertResult("SOME RESULT HERE, I.E. INT VALUE")`. Подробнее тут: [Testing RxJava](https://medium.com/@vanniktech/testing-rxjava-code-made-easy-4cc32450fc9a). Ну или даже заставить метод отработать синхронно вызвав `.toBlocking()`. Но это будет нарушением самой идеи либы и, засим, костылём.
3. Возможно что-то получится, если использовать корутины из языка [kotlin](/questions/tagged/kotlin), которые позволяют писать асинхронный код в синхронном стиле. Но тут я не уверен и сама эта фича всё ещё, вроде, эксперементальна.